# Brightness controls doesn't work on a MacBook Pro 5.5

Tags: brightness, macbook-pro

I recently installed Ubuntu on my MacBook pro 5.5 (mid 2009). I have a problem with the brightness control. The thing is, when I try to reduce the brightness of my display which would help my battery life dramaticlly is doesnt work.

I tried to use the system preference but no succes. I tried to look of it changes something if disconnect the computer from the charge I the screen will dimm but once against I failed.

I tried many things such as pommed or Many other little things that I have had read on forums.

Answer (score 1):

No mention of what Ubuntu you are using so this is a SWAG.

Recommend /etc/pommed.conf:

```
#
# Configuration file for pommed
#

# General configuration
general {
    # fnmode: functions keys first (no need to use fn) or last
    # Value is either 1 or 2, effect is hardware-dependent
    fnmode = 2
}

# sysfs backlight control
# nVidia machines, will fall back to nv8600gmt if not supported by the kernel
lcd_sysfs {
    # The sysfs backlight control is a generic interface provided
    # by the Linux kernel for backlight control on most graphic cards.
    # The brightness range can differ depending on the hardware.

    # initial backlight level [12] (0 - 15, -1 to disable)
    init = -1
    # step value (1 - 2)
    step = 1
    # backlight level when on battery [6] (1 - 15, 0 to disable)
    on_batt = 6
}

# ATI X1600 backlight control (MacBook Pro v1 & v2)
lcd_x1600 {
    # initial backlight level [200] (0 - 255, -1 to disable)
    init = -1
    # step value (1 - 127)
    step = 10
    # backlight level when on battery [80] (1 - 255, 0 to disable)
    on_batt = 80
}

# Intel 945GM, 965GM backlight control (MacBook v1-v4, MacBook Air v1)
lcd_gma950 {
    # initial backlight level [0x6f] (0x1f - 0x94 usually, -1 to disable)
    init = -1
    # step value (0x01 - 0x20)
    step = 0x0f
    # backlight level when on battery [0x40] (0x1f - 0x94 usually, 0 to disable)
    on_batt = 0x40
}

# nVidia GeForce 8600M GT/9400M/9600M GT backlight control
# (MacBook Pro v3-v5, MacBook v5, MacBook v2)
lcd_nv8600mgt {
    # initial backlight level [12] (0 - 15, -1 to disable)
    init = -1
    # step value (1 - 2)
    step = 1
    # backlight level when on battery [6] (1 - 15, 0 to disable)
    on_batt = 6
}

# Audio support
audio {
    # Use amixer or alsamixer/alsamixergui to determine the sound card
    # and the mixer elements to use here.

    # sound card to use
    card = "default"
    # initial volume [80] (0 - 100%, -1 to disable)
    init = -1
    # step value (1 - 50%)
    step = 10
    # beep on volume change
    beep = yes
    # mixer element for volume adjustment
    volume = "PCM"
    # mixer element for muting the speakers
    speakers = "Front"
    # mixer element for muting the headphones
    headphones = "Headphone"
}

# Keyboard backlight control
kbd {
    # default value for automatic backlight (0 - 255)
    default = 100
    # step value (1 - 127)
    step = 10
    # ambient light thresholds for automatic backlight (0 - 255)
    on_threshold = 20
    off_threshold = 40
    # enable/disable automatic backlight
    auto = no
    # idle timer - switches off keyboard backlight automatically (timeout in seconds, -1 to disable)
    idle_timer = -1
    # idle tickms - timer tick rate in milliseconds
    idle_tickms = 200
}

# CD/DVD drive ejection
eject {
    # enable/disable eject key
    enabled = yes
    # CD/DVD device
    device = "/dev/dvd"
}

# Beeper
beep {
    # enable/disable beeper
    enabled = no
    # WAV file to use (from pommed: goutte.wav or click.wav in /usr/share/pommed)
    beepfile = "/usr/share/pommed/goutte.wav"
}

# Apple Remote - deprecated
# Note: the appleir driver is required for this to work; this driver has been
# obsoleted with Linux 2.6.22, so unless you are running a kernel < 2.6.22 or
# use the appleir driver on a newer kernel, this won't work.
# You should use LIRC instead.
appleir {
    # enable/disable the appleir support
    enabled = no
}
```

[source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1825981)

Comment: What does SWAG stand for? I can tell what you mean from context clues, but am curious. In before swag jokes.