# How to make FN keys working on Asus G75 laptop

Tags: shortcut-keys, laptop, asus

**EDIT**

As Tholap said, all I needed was a kernel update, which is effective for a little while now

**END EDIT**

I just bought a Asus G75 and I cannot make the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys working.
I only found how to control the brightness (http://askubuntu.com/questions/126441/brightness-controls-doesnt-work-on-a-macbook-pro-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts) but the other keys are not recognized.

I didn't know much things about key binding before digging, but I tried :

- testing with xev : no output...
- testing with keymap : no output...
- modprobe asus-laptop : 
  `FATAL: Error inserting asus_laptop (/lib/modules/3.2.0-25-generic/kernel/drivers/platform/x86/asus-laptop.ko): No such device` (not sure what that means)
- modprobe asus-nb-wmi : `FATAL: Error inserting asus_nb_wmi (/lib/modules/3.2.0-25-generic/drivers/platform/x86/asus-nb-wmi.ko): No such device` (not sure what that means)

Thanks for your advice

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and looked for a solution. Couldn't find anything that made a difference. The kernel simply doesn't produce any scancodes for most of the Fn key combinations. I guess we'll have to wait for a newer kernel with updated drivers.

This command shows scancodes:

```
sudo /lib/udev/keymap -i input/event3
```

Some combinations do work:

- Fn+F1 - sleep
- Fn+F2 - toggle wifi
- Fn+F7 - toggle screen on/off
- Fn+Del - Ins

Comment: thanks, but on my laptop, the toggle Wifi does not work, which is not a big deal ; I'd love to have the sound volume working, however...

Answer (score 0):

I was ignorantly using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key with the <kbd>F1-12</kbd> keys up top. The Function key is <kbd>Fn</kbd> next to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key. You knew that, right? Press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and a F# key up top.

If this doesn't work: Try powering off. Unplug the cord from DC or AC outlet. Take the battery out and put it back in. Then power on. Your computer might revert back to working better.

Comment: Thanks, but that's working for a little while now. I don't know which kernel update did the trick. Editing my question