# MacBookPro 5,4, brightness problem

Tags: brightness, macbook-pro

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my macbookPro 5,4 and it seems like everything is working well expect the brightness control.

The functions keys are working and when pressing it I see the brightness bar changing, but the brightness doesn't change.

Changing the brightness from the settings tools doesn't work as well.

Any idea?

Comment: Change the brightness using Fn key and immediately run the command in terminal.'  dmesg | tail  '. Post the output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after reading [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126441/brightness-controls-doesnt-work-on-a-macbook-pro-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts) , I just edited:

`sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf`

and added the line:

`Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"`.

that's it!

Answer (score 0):

There are a multitude of reasons why the brightness won't work on the Macbook.

do you see any  backlight  device under /sys/class/backlight?

if there is more than one folder there it possible that the backlight utility is trying to change the backligt on the improper device. This is the Case with the Macbook Pro 15" 8.2 model.

If there is only one. device. You can try setting backlight manually just to see if it works. by typing:

```
cat max_brightness | sudo tee  -a > brightness
```

this will read the value of the file max_brightness and set that value to the current brightness.

If there is no backlight device. You don't have a proper backlight module installed.
it should be called apple_bl , or nvidia_bl, 
try to load them manually using modprobe modulename , and verifying if any device pops up in the folder.