# 18.04 no screen brightness control on MacBook Pro

Tags: 18.04, brightness, macbook-pro

Just installed Ubuntu 18.04 on a MacBook Pro, mid-2009, 13" scren, Core2 Duo CPU and GeForce 9400 GPU.  It took a little looking around and tinkering to install and get WiFi up and running after upgrading RAM to 4 GB to overcome hang issues.

The screen brightness controls do not function, can anyone please help?

Comment: Which MacBook Pro do you have? Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacBook_Pro#Technical_specifications_2

Comment: @K7AAY its a 13" mid 2009 MBP with a Core 2 Duo processor, GeForce 9400 graphics,

Comment: Please try https://askubuntu.com/a/192074/197910 . found be a search on _[macbook-pro] brightness_ in the search box above

Comment: Related: [18.04 can't adjust screen brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad T510](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227049/968501)

Answer (score 0):

This solution works for a Macbook Pro with NVidia geforce card under Ubuntu 16 LTS:

In a terminal edit 'xorg.conf' file:

```
sudo gedit /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Add a new commande line in "Device" Section (see below "#"):

```
Section "Device"
  Identifier     "Device0"
  Driver         "nvidia"
  VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
  BoardName      "GeForce 320M"

#This following line actually enables the brightness control
  Option  "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```