# 18.04 can't adjust screen brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad T510

Tags: 18.04, brightness, thinkpad

I upgraded my Lenovo ThinkPad T510 from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

At first the PC would freeze, but I fixed it with [Ubuntu Bionic Beaver freezes randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224086/ubuntu-bionic-beaver-freezes-randomly)

Now, I can't adjust the screen brightness.

The output of `sudo lshw -C display`  is:

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GT218M [NVS 3100M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:34 memory:cc000000-ccffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:ce000000-cfffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**Update #1:** @Raffa, here are the results:

```
ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1350 oct 21 09:26 10-quirks.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  945 abr 11  2018 40-libinput.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  149 nov 18 09:11 nvidia-drm-outputclass-ubuntu.conf
```

**Update #2:** Output of `lspci | grep -i vga` :

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT218M [NVS 3100M] (rev a2)
```

**Update #3:** Hi @Raffa, I've created the new configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` as you suggested and I can adjust the screen brightness now. Thanks a lot for helping me again.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Comment: Please also add the output of `lspci | grep -i vga`

Comment: Well done and you are most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please create and edit a new configuration file in `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` like so:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf
```

Then, copy and paste the following into it:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Quadro NVS 3100M"
    Option         "RegistryDwords" "EnableBrightnessControl=1"
EndSection
```

Then, save the file and exit the editor by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> then press <kbd>y</kbd> then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

After that reboot your system and see if screen brightness adjusts now.

Answer (score 0):

The config-file `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf` is working too for:

Thinkpad t410, Nvidia. After Upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04.

I had the same output for:

```
$ sudo lshw -C display
```

and

```
$ lspci | grep -i vga
```

and a comparable output for:

```
$ ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Now brightness adjustment is possible via `fn-key-combination` and via the slider in the system-menu.