# Can't change brightness in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, brightness

I can't change the brightness in Kubuntu 18.04. I tried to do it with the keyboard shortcuts (<kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd>) and in the *Battery and brightness* section in the Task Manager.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `ls -l /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 can't adjust screen brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad T510](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227049/18-04-cant-adjust-screen-brightness-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t510)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As just a simply workaround you can use the following command-line to set your brightness:

```
echo 255 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/*/brightness >/dev/null
```

Change the `255` value with one from `0` to `255` to move from `min` to `max` value.

Comment: So i suppose there is no easier way to do that, right?

Comment: I suppose you have some trouble with the display configuration, so to solve the issue from the root, you have to found the original problem.