# Screen brightness not adjusting on Lenovo ThinkPad E585 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, lenovo, brightness, thinkpad

I can't adjust the brightness on my laptop.

Hopefully helpful reference info:
Device: Lenovo ThinkPad E585
CPU: Ryzen 3
GPU: AMD Radeon Vega Graphics
OS ver.: Ubuntu 20.04

When I click the upper right corner and move the brightness scrubber left or right, there's no change in the actual screen brightness.

I've searched here, but links like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227049/18-04-cant-adjust-screen-brightness-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t510) seem to only deal with Nvidia GPUs. Mine has a built in Radeon Vega graphics, so I'm not sure if the procedure is the same. I tried installing amdgpu-pro-install, but that gave me issues with a blank screen after reboot, so I ended up having to uninstall it afterward.

Let me know what you guys think or any more information I need to edit this post and add.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was solved by updating to the latest linux kernel (5.7 should also be okay), which includes better support for AMD graphics. I used [this guide](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/install-linux-kernel-5-8-ubuntu/) to update my kernel to 5.8. Hope that helps!

Comment: I updated the Kernel to 5.8, but it still isn't working. I do appreciate the help, though!