# After installing newer Nvidia driver - Brightness locks at MAX

Tags: nvidia

Everytime i try to install a newer Nvidia drive ( either v455 and 460 ), my brightness locks at max, and even though the FN keys work and i actually see the brightness bar decreasing... it doesn't change anything, brightness stays at max.

Some aditional info:

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.1
Kernel: 5.8.0-36-generic ( i also tried 5.9 series, doesn't change anything )
Nvidia driver: 450.102.04
Nvidia card: GTX 1070 (dedicated)
Laptop: HP Omen 15

Things i've tried:

- Added the graphics PPA, so now my driver manager shows nvidia 460 available instead of 455. Anyway, the problem remains the same.
- Tried a newer kernel, no joy either.
- Added the following to my grub file:
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_backlight=vendor"
  No joy either.

Comment: Are you trying to say that newer isn't always better? If so, I agree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 can't adjust screen brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad T510](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227049/18-04-cant-adjust-screen-brightness-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t510)

Comment: @mikewhatever i'm learning that, yes :)

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes here with the same issue: Waiting for the bug fix: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-455/+bug/1905591