# How do I adjust screen brightness in Kubuntu 20.10 using a NVIDIA card?

Tags: nvidia, package-management, kubuntu

After installing Kubuntu 20.10 on my laptop with a NVIDIA Geforce GTX 1650 card, I can't lower the screen brightness. I have also installed the latest version on the Geforce GTX 1650 driver from the NVIDIA website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [18.04 can't adjust screen brightness on Lenovo Thinkpad T510](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227049/18-04-cant-adjust-screen-brightness-on-lenovo-thinkpad-t510)

Comment: I tried it now my screen is blank on booting up.

Comment: You probably copied and pasted without modifying to your hardware specs. Please follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163516/problems-with-booting-the-system/1163539#1163539) to get into recovery moot then after step # 6 run `rm /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-nvidia-brightness.conf` to remove the file you just created then reboot your system and [edit] to add the output of `sudo lshw -C display` and `lspci | grep -i vga`