# Brightness control not working on 2009 MacBook

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, brightness, macbook-pro

After I installed the proprietary Nvidia drivers on my mid 2009 MacBook Pro running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 the brightness control doesn't work. It works when I am using the open source driver, but I need to use the proprietary driver.

Comment: same problem here. Tried various recommended approaches including this recommendation:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/126441/brightness-controls-doesnt-work-on-a-macbook-pro-5-5-ubuntu-12-04-lts?rq=1