# There is no xorg.conf. How does ubuntu store user configurations of screen resolution?

Tags: xorg, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and the default desktop environment. I can't find /etc/X11/xorg.conf or /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/ or similar files or directories. But, I can change the screen resolution, and the settings persist after I restart my computer. My question is: where does the system store the configurations of screen resolution set by a user? Are the configurations in a file somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check `sudo ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` there you should find a bunch of files corresponding to your current video drivers etc.

The second part of your question, regarding knowing what resultion to display: this will be dependent on your current desktop environment in use. One user can end up with different screen resolutions upon login if they have two different desktop environments like Gnome and XFCE installed for their Ubuntu distro.

For example, I use XFCE4 and mine is in `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/displays.xml`. If you use something else, you will likely find the display config file somewhere in your $HOME folder, for gnome if I recall correctly it 
can be found by `cat ~/.config/monitors.xml`

Comment: Yes, I am using gnome, and I find ~/.config/monitors.xml. Thank you! That's what I wanted. I will accept your answer, though my reputation is too low to vote.

Comment: editing ~/.config/monitors.xml had no impact for me trying to add `rate 60` in pop 20.10 on a G5 5590 with a 144hz panel. Still stuck with 144hz, which I'm assuming currently is the reason integrated graphics mode fails, which is what I'm trying to fix.