# Enable middle mouse button touchpad emulation for xubuntu 18.04 on Dell XPS 15

Tags: xubuntu, touchpad, xfce, synaptics, multi-touch

How can I map a three-finger tab on the touchpad to a middle mouse click? In [another question](https://askubuntu.com/a/518612/191312) I've found

```
synclient TapButton3=2
```

and this works, but it seems a bit strange to run a shell script on each startup. Isn't there a configuration anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved in an Xorg config file. First create the directory `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` and copy `70-synaptics.conf` over from `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/`

```
sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
sudo cp  /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/70-synaptics.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/
```

Then change it to

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad catchall"
        Driver "synaptics"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

        Option          "TapButton1"            "1"
        Option          "TapButton2"            "3"     # multitouch
        Option          "TapButton3"            "2"     # multitouch
EndSection
```

This [blog post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2123353) explains the new layout of the X11 config files:

> The /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d is for the Distro's and you are not 
>   suppose to muck with stuff in there. Instead the user is suppose to put 
>   custom files in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d. You may need to create that directory. The .conf files in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d run after the ones in
>   /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d so they control or override anything in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d. Despite that I still usually number them a bit higher. So if I'm modifying the 50-wacom.conf in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d I'll call the custom .conf file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d 52-wacom.conf. Maybe a bit of overkill.

For explanations on the available options, see [the debian wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/SynapticsTouchpad)